# MarkLogic - Query Options with extract-document-data

Tags: marklogic, marklogic-9, marklogic-dhf

MarkLogic version 9.0-6.2

I am trying to extract a portion of the envelope (example given below) using extract-document-data in Query options.

```
{
  "envelope": {
    "headers": {
      "audit": {
        "created-by": "admin", 
        "last-updated-by": "*******"
      }
    }, 
    "instance": {
       "UserId": "Test1",
       "UserName":"TestName"
       "Phones":[
         {
           "PhoneType":"Home",
           "PhoneNum":"18009897800"
         },
         {
           "PhoneType":"Cell",
           "PhoneNum":"1239897800"
         }
       ]
    }
  }
}
```

My requirement is just to return UserId and UserName. So I tried below code in Options file.

```
"extract-document-data":
          {
          "selected": "exclude",
          "extract-path": [ "/envelope/instance/Phones" ]
          },
"extract-document-data":
          {
          "selected": "include",
          "extract-path": [ "/envelope/instance" ]
          }
```

I am getting the response as below

```
{
"instance": {
       "UserId": "Test1",
       "UserName":"TestName"
       "Phones":[
         {
           "PhoneType":"Home",
           "PhoneNum":"18009897800"
         },
         {
           "PhoneType":"Cell",
           "PhoneNum":"123989780"
         }
       ]
    }
}
```

This code is not excluding the "Phones" property. Also, returning "instance" property in the output, but I just need the UserId and UserName.

How can I code both exclude and include in the same options file? Also, in the include path, how do I specify just the descendants to be returned (in my case, descendants of "instance" property.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Does the response extract the right data with a specification similar to the following?

```
"extract-document-data": {
      "selected": "include",
      "extract-path": [
          "/envelope/instance/(UserId|UserName)"
          ]
      }
```

Hoping that helps,

Comment: Thanks a lot for the quick response! This is returning each property as a seperate JSON object as in ...{"UserId":"Test1"}, {"UserName":"TestName"}. I am calling the function with multiple inputs, so unless each set (UserId and UserName) is in the same json object, I may not be able to relate them.

Comment: Does changing "selected" from "include" to "include-with-ancestors" return the correct data structure?

Comment: Perfect! Working as expected. Thank You!

Comment: Just a curious question. Though "include-with-ancestors" works well, it means that I need to change the code in Options file, every time there is a new property   under instance, where as my need is just to exclude "Phones" property. Just wondering if there is a way to specify both include and exclude in the same options file.

Comment: To my knowledge, that is currently not possible. It would also be difficult to tell the system which should be stronger. If you really want to avoid `Phones`, but not spell out the props explicitly, then include the entire instance, and use a REST transform to weed out the details that should not get exposed. If it needs to be secure, you could look into Element Level Security..