# MarkLogic - Query Options - exclude array from json object using extract-document-data

Tags: marklogic, marklogic-9, marklogic-dhf

MarkLogic version - 9.0-6.2

I have a json document as below, from which I need to exclude the "PhoneInfo" property before returning.

```
{
  "PersonInfo":
    {
      "Name": "Test",
      "Age": "26",
      "PhoneInfo":[
         {
           "PhoneType":"Home",
           "PhoneNumber":"1233453456"
         },
         {
           "PhoneType":"Cell",
           "PhoneNumber":"6233459865"
         }
      ] 
    }
}
```

I am using below code in Options file to exclude the "PhoneInfo" property

```
"extract-document-data": 
          {
          "selected": "exclude",
          "extract-path": [ "/PersonInfo/PhoneInfo" ]
          }
```

However, I am getting below response, with PhoneInfo as empty array.

```
{
  "PersonInfo":
    {
      "Name": "Test",
      "Age": "26",
      "PhoneInfo":[]
    }
}
```

Is there a way I can completely exclude the PhoneInfo property using Options file?

Comment: Looks almost identical to https://stackoverflow.com/q/53638681/918496